# Help with Triggers / Classes for Case Creation based on Field Change in Customer_Asset

Tags: apex, trigger, class, case-object

I am new to Salesforce and haven't coded in quite awhile, so please forgive my rookie mistake(s).

I am attempting to write a trigger to do the following:

Our company manufactures equipment that occasionally requires software updates.   What we want to do is the following:

Intent:  Create an automatic process that generates cases based on Customer Asset and Firmware Version.

**Current setup:**

- Object named Firmware Version
- Object named Firmware Update Available
- E-mail Template - Software Update (includes Update Revision Notes, Update File, Instructions to implement)

**Current Workflow:**

Checks Object - Firmware Update Available and Verifies current Firmware Version < New Version Number

If True -> E-mail Notification sent out to customer(s) with attachments.

Task Created under Instrument that requests Service open a ticket.

**What we need:**

Case is created for each separate asset for each customer.
E-mail Template that is sent from case includes all relevant information and attachments.
Customers then respond to case (via email2case) that update is complete.

**Roadblock:**

No "Out of the Box" App that can generate a case from workflow, task, or asset.

**Help Requested:**

Does anyone have a visualforce or javascript they have used that does this?  Alternately, can someone point me in the right direction to create this functionality?

***Here is the code I have written so far***

```
public with sharing class FirmwareClass{

public void createCases(List<Customer_Asset__c> assets){
  List<Customer_Asset__c> casesToCreate = new List<Customer_Asset__c>();

  for(Customer_Asset__c acc:assets){
        if (Customer_Asset__c.Firmware_Update_Available__c = TRUE){
         Case caseToAdd = new Case();
         caseToAdd.AccountId = acc.Account__c;
         caseToAdd.Customer_Model__c = Customer_Asset__c.Instrument__c;
         caseToAdd.Subject = 'Software Upgrade Available';
            }       
  } 
  insert Case;
}
```

---

And this is the Trigger:

```
 trigger FirmwareTrigger on Customer_Asset__c (after update) {
   FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
   if((Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) || (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)){
     // Now call your helper method
     helper.createCaseWhenNeeded(Trigger.new);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Bill. So you need help with how to create a Case from a trigger? Does your createCases() method work?

Comment: VisualForce code would only be of use in your customer portal and you'd need a custom controller for it. Obviously, NOT the way to go. I think you're on the right track. Until the object is "touched" by an update, the trigger won't fire to generate the case. If you need the case in place sooner, rethink your logic so an update is still generated.

Comment: Hi Mike,

No my createCases() method is failing.

Comment: Let me try that again :)

FirmwareClass: Variable does not exist: Case

Comment: @crmprogdev - Thanks for the comment!  I'm stuck on getting the case to generate.  My intent is that once the records are updated, the trigger fires and creates the cases.  Then I can use a list view and mass e-mail the update to the users that need the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost have it. Your FirmwareClass method looks like it needs a few corrections. Try:

```
public with sharing class FirmwareClass{

public void createCases(List<Customer_Asset__c> assets){
  List<Case> casesToCreate = new List<Case>();

  for(Customer_Asset__c acc:assets){
        if (acc.Firmware_Update_Available__c == TRUE){
         Case caseToAdd = new Case();
         caseToAdd.AccountId = acc.Account__c;
         caseToAdd.Customer_Model__c = acc.Instrument__c;
         caseToAdd.Subject = 'Software Upgrade Available';
         casesToCreate.add(caseToAdd);
            }       
  } 
  if (casesToCreate.size() > 0)
      insert casesToCreate;
}
```

Also, your trigger looks like it is calling the wrong method. It should be  helper.createCases.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code, so it may have a syntax error or two.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It's close.  I'm getting an error now:

FirmwareClass: Illegal assignment from Schema.SobjectField to String.  DO I need to change the field type?

Comment: What line number is the error on?

Comment: Line 10, column 10

Comment: Oops, missed a couple things. I've updated the code. You had the object name (Customer_Asset__c) instead of the variable (acc) name.

Comment: Ok Fixed that problem by just removing that line.  I can always go in and change the Asset Name manually if I have to.  At the moment I just want to get the cases created.  I am now getting an error "Line 7, column 13: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, String    The Field is a checkbox, I had assumed it TRUE would respond as a checkmark.

Comment: Did you use the new code I edited? That comparison had the same problem: object name vs variable name.

Comment: Ok now the error I am getting is: "Line 10, Column 10: Field is not writeable: Case.Customer_Model__c"

I'm going to take that line out I think for now.

Comment: Yup.  Taking that part out appears to have fixed it.

Thank you everyone for the great support!!!!

Comment: @BillPomeroy, don't forget to vote the answer up as well.