# Trigger Hel(p) Code Coverage 0%

Tags: apex, trigger, class, case-object

As a followup to my [previous posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13099/help-with-triggers-classes-for-case-creation-part-ii-test-classes) (Again, many many thanks) I am still having trouble with the trigger.

The code seems to function and I created a test class and the code itself is 100% covered.

The Trigger will not work, I am getting 0% coverage and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger FirmwareTrigger on Customer_Asset__c ( after insert) {        

 List<Customer_Asset__c> listfirm = new list<Customer_Asset__c>();
      for (Customer_Asset__c ta: trigger.new)
 {

List <Customer_Asset__c> firmup = [SELECT Id FROM Customer_Asset__c WHERE Firmware_Update_Available__c = TRUE];

   FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
   for (Customer_Asset__c az: Trigger.new);
    helper.createCases(Trigger.new);
  }
}
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest (seeAlldata=true)
private class FirmwareClassTest {
private static testMethod void testCreateCases() {
    //create a new instance of a Customer_Asset__c to use in the test

List<Customer_Asset__c> testAssets = new List<Customer_Asset__c> {};
    Customer_Asset__c ta = new Customer_Asset__C();
        ta.Firmware_Update_Available__c = True;

//add additional required fields to the ta (you may need to create an account and other supporting records)

    testAssets.add(ta);
    insert testAssets;
    update testAssets;
    FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
    Test.startTest();
    helper.createCases(testAssets);
    Test.stopTest();

    // query for cases to see if some were created and do an assertion
}

//do some updating that you want to test

}
```

**Class**

```
public with sharing class FirmwareClass{
   public void createCases(List<Customer_Asset__c> assets){

List<Case> casesToCreate = new List<Case>();

   for(Customer_Asset__c acc:assets){
       if (acc.Firmware_Update_Available__c == TRUE){
    Case caseToAdd = new Case();
    caseToAdd.AccountId = acc.Account__c;
    caseToAdd.Subject = 'Software Upgrade Available';
     casesToCreate.add(caseToAdd);
    }       
 } 
  if (casesToCreate.size() > 0)
  insert casesToCreate;
}

}
```

I tried to get fancy and added (what I hoped / thought) would be some sort of validation within the trigger.

**Updated Trigger**

```
trigger FirmwareTrigger on Customer_Asset__c (before update) {

 List<FirmwareUpdate> listfirm = new list<FirmwareUpdate>();
      for (Customer_Asset__c ta: trigger.new)
 {
  FirmwareUpdate firmup = [SELECT Firmware_Update_Available__c FROM Customer_Asset__c];
if (firmup == 1)
{
       FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
       for (Customer_Asset__c az: Trigger.new);
        helper.createCases(Trigger.new);
      }
}
}
```

I receive a compile error with the New Trigger:

Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: FirmwareUpdate at line 3 column 47

The old trigger compiles but is showing a 0 code coverage.   At this point I am stuck.  I believe my class works, but I can't get past this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your trigger fires on before update

```
trigger FirmwareTrigger on Customer_Asset__c (before update)
```

yet your test class just INSERTS records, call update on the testAssets list in FirmwareClassTest to fire the trigger

btw. your trigger creates a case every time a asset gets updated no matter if Firmware_Update_Available__c is changed to true or not

here's updated code

**TRIGGER**

```
trigger FirmwareTrigger on Customer_Asset__c (before update) {

  // hold assets for which cases need to be created
  List<Customer_Asset__c> fwUpdates = new List<Customer_Asset__c>();

  for (Customer_Asset__c record:trigger.new)
  {
     // make sure we only include assets for which Firmware_Update_Available__c has been changed to true
     if (record.Firmware_Update_Available__c &&
        !trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).Firmware_Update_Available__c){

        fwUpdates.add(record);
     }        
  }

  // call FWClass only if there are any assets for which cases need to be created
  if (fwUpdates.size() > 0){
     FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
     helper.createCases(fwUpdates);
  }
}
```

trigger FirmwareTrigger on Customer_Asset__c (before update) {

List listfirm = new list();
      for (Customer_Asset__c ta: trigger.new)
 {
  FirmwareUpdate firmup = [SELECT Firmware_Update_Available__c FROM Customer_Asset__c];
if (firmup == 1)
{
       FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
       for (Customer_Asset__c az: Trigger.new);
        helper.createCases(Trigger.new);
      }
}
}

**TEST CLASS**

```
@isTest
private class FirmwareClassTest {

   static List<Customer_Asset__c> getTestAssets(){
    List<Customer_Asset__c> testAssets = new List<Customer_Asset__c> {};
    Customer_Asset__c ta = new Customer_Asset__C();
    ta.Firmware_Update_Available__c = True;
    testAssets.add(ta);
    return testAssets;
   }

   // test FirmwareClass.createCases
   private static testMethod void testCreateCases() {

    List<Customer_Asset__c> testAssets = getTestAssets();

    FirmwareClass helper = new FirmwareClass();
    Test.startTest();
    helper.createCases(testAssets);
    Test.stopTest();
   }

   // test FirmwareTrigger.trigger
   private static testMethod void testFirmwareTrigger() {

    // insert the asserts with update available false
    List<Customer_Asset__c> testAssets = getTestAssets();
    testAssets[0].Firmware_Update_Available__c = false;
    insert testAssets;

    Test.startTest();
    // now set update available to true
    testAssets[0].Firmware_Update_Available__c = true;
    // that should cause the trigger to create cases
    update testAssets;
    Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Seb__Wagner,

I see what you are talking about but I am not sure how to fix it.  Any changes I try to make seem to give me compile errors.

Comment: @BillPomeroy included revised code in my answer, that should do the trick. btw. you get the compile error because there's no class/object called FirmwareUpdate, and you try to assign a list of type Customer_Asset__c from a SOQL query to list of type FirmwareUpdate

Comment: You did it!!! 

Works like a champ!!!!!   Your the best!

Answer (score 1):

- Your trigger is an update trigger (before update, after update) it fires on an update to the Customer_Asset__c object.
- Your test Class does not create or Update and Customer_Asset__c records.
- You need to add an insert and then an update of Customer_Asset__c records within the test class.

```
    insert testAssets;
    //do some updating that you want to test
    update testAssets;
```